# How to expose a directory to a container?

Tags: systemd, systemd-nspawn

I would like to expose to a container (Ubuntu 16.04 created with `debootstrap`) started with `systemd-nspawn` a directory of the host system (also an Ubuntu 16.04). **Is this possible with `systemd-nspawn`?**

I would fallback on some NFS based solution (the host exposes the directory which is mounted by the guest) but a `systemd` native solution would be ideal.

Comment: Would the `--bind` option work for you?

Comment: @StephenHarris: I do not know how I could have missed that in the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html#--bind=). Thanks. If you do not mind to turn the comment into an answer I will gladly accept it as this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `systemd-nspawn` command [has a `--bind` option](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html#--bind=) that lets you "bind mount" a directory from the host filesystem into the container.

If you just do `--bind /path/to/dir` then it will appear in that name inside the container.

If you do `--bind /path/to/dir:/foo` then it will show up as `/foo` inside the container.

In order to use it in a configuration file (`/etc/systemd/nspawn/<container>.nspawn`), add the `Bind=` directive to its `[Files]` section.

Comment: And what about file system permissions? The bound directory is owned by nobody:nogroup user, right? What if I want to bind mount my host's `/home` directory to the containers `/home` directory, how do I do that properly? And even more, is there a way to inherit host's list of users (real users) by a container?

Comment: @krokoziabla you should really create a new question explaining your setup and problem, what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Done :-) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393584/systemd-nspawn-file-system-permissions-for-a-bound-folder