# systemd-nspawn: file-system permissions for a bound folder

Tags: systemd-nspawn

**What I have:**

A Gentoo host and an Ubuntu container.

**What I want:**

Mount `/home` from the host to the container and use it there as normal.

**What I'm doing:**

Start the container with `-U --bind=/home` flags.

**What I get:**

In the container I have my `/home` directory but it has been mounted with nobody:nogroup owner:

```
scratch:5:0:/home/vkirsano> ll /home 
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  3 nobody nogroup  4096 Sep 19 17:39 krokoziabla
drwx------  2 nobody nogroup 16384 Oct 20  2016 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 56 nobody nogroup  4096 Sep 20 22:15 vkirsano
```

So effectively I only have read-only access to the contents of the `/home` directory which is not what I want. Say, I've created user `vkirsano` in the container with the same UID:GID as in the host so I would like systemd-nspawn to just keep the original info about files' ownership while binding the directory.

**What I'm asking**

What is the usual practice (if there is one) of mounting folders like `/home` with keeping the ability to work normally with them in the container?

Comment: Do you have SELINUX enabled?

Comment: No, I don't have SELINUX

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, `-U` is mostly incompatible with rw `--bind`.  From the [docs:](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html#--bind=)

> Note that when this option is used in combination with
>   --private-users, the resulting mount points will be owned by the nobody user. That's because the mount and its files and directories
>   continue to be owned by the relevant host users and groups, which do
>   not exist in the container, and thus show up under the wildcard UID
>   65534 (nobody). If such bind mounts are created, it is recommended to
>   make them read-only, using --bind-ro=.

I've used nspawn to make Ubuntu-based containers for building Yocto on my Arch Linux host.  When Arch's kernel enabled `CONFIG_USER_NS=y`, I needed to set `PrivateUsers=off` in my `/etc/systemd/nspawn/foo.nspawn` files.  (Also, I add a user with the same UID in both the host and container, so I can `Bind=` and access it the same way in both the container and host.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It helped me understand and diagnose a related problem I was having. I wanted to ask for clarification, but I thought it was best to [ask a separate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557293/how-can-i-make-a-device-like-dev-mapper-control-available-inside-a-systemd-nspa).